# Find the time period with the maximum number of overlapping intervals

Tags: algorithm

There is one very famous problem. I am asking the same here.
There is number of elephants time span given, here time span means, year of birth to year of death.
You have to calculate the period where maximum number of elephants are alive.

**Example:**

```
1990 - 2013
1995 - 2000
2010 - 2020
1992 - 1999

Answer is   1995 - 1999
```

I tried hard to solve this, but I am unable to do so.

How can I solve this problem?

I got approach for when a user asks to find the number of elephants in any year. I solved that by using segment tree, whenever any elephants time span given, increase every year of that time span by 1. We can solve that in this way. Can this be used to solve the above problem?

**For above question, I only need the high-level approach, I will code it myself.**

Comment: Actually I have an approach if user asks for the year where maximum number of elephants alive. But not for period.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Split each date range into start date and end date.
- Sort the dates. If a start date and an end date are the same, put the end date first (otherwise you could get an empty date range as the best).
- Start with a count of 0.
- Iterate through the dates using a [sweep-line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm):

  - If you get a start date:

    - Increment the count.
    - If the current count is higher than the last best count, set the count, store this start date and set a flag.
  - If you get an end date:

    - If the flag is set, store the stored start date and this end date with the count as the best interval so far.
    - Reset the flag.
    - Decrement the count.

**Example:**

For input:

```
1990 - 2013
1995 - 2000
2010 - 2020
1992 - 1999
```

Split and sorted: (`S` = start, `E` = end)

```
1990 S, 1992 S, 1995 S, 1999 E, 2000 E, 2010 S, 2013 E, 2020 E
```

Iterating through them:

```
count = 0
lastStart = N/A
1990: count = 1
      count = 1 > 0, so set flag
        and lastStart = 1990

1992: count = 2
      count = 2 > 0, so set flag
        and lastStart = 1992

1995: count = 3
      count = 3 > 0, so set flag
        and lastStart = 1995

1999: flag is set, so
        record [lastStart (= 1995), 1999] with a count of 3
      reset flag
      count = 2

2000: flag is not set
      reset flag
      count = 1

2010: count = 2
      since count = 2 < 3, don't set flag

2013: flag is not set
      reset flag
      count = 1

2020: flag is not set
      reset flag
      count = 0
```

Comment: For a (very) large number of elephants, it might be worth skipping the sort. You could create an array indexed by year with +1 for birth, -1 for death. O(e) to fill, and O(n) to sweep, where `e` is number of elephants and `n` is date range.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Say I have all the above data stored in a file. Read it into two arrays separated by the " - ".

Hence, now I have `birthYear[]` which contains all the birth years and `deathYear[]` containing all the death years.

so birthYear[] = [1990, 1995, 2010, 1992]
   deathYear[] = [2013, 2000, 2020, 1999]

Get the min birth year and the max death year. Create a Hashtable with the Key as a year, and the Value as the count.

Hence,

```
HashTable<String, Integer> numOfElephantsAlive = new HashTable<String, Integer>();
```

Now, from the min(BirthYear) to the max(BirthYear), do the following :

Iterate through the Birth Year Array and do an add to the HashTable all the years in between the BirthYear and Corresponding DeathYear with the count being 1. If the key already exists, add 1 to it. Hence, for the last case :

```
1992 - 1999
HashTable.put(1992, 1)
HashTable.put(1993, 1)
and so on for every year.

Say, for example, you have a Hashtable that looks like this at the end of it:

Key    Value
1995     3
1996     3
1992     2
1993     1
1994     3
1998     1
1997     2
1999     2
```

Now, you need the range of the Years when the number of elephants were maximum. Hence, let's iterate and find the year with the max value. This is pretty easy. Iterate over the keySet() and get the year.

Now, you need a contiguous range of years. You can either do this in two ways:

Do Collections.sort() over the keySet() and when you hit the max value, save all contiguous locations.

Hence, on hitting 3 for our example at 1994, we would check for all the following years with a 3. This will return you your range which is the min-year, max-year combo.

Comment: I didn't uderstand your answer. Please elaborate. I think your example is wrong.

Comment: Ahh.. you want the range of years. Ok... Let me update my solution.

Answer (score 0):

One approach maybe:
Iterate through the periods. Keep track of a list of periods up to now. Note: At each step, the number of periods increases by 2 (or 1 if there is no overlap with the existing list of periods).
For example

```
1990 - 2013
Period List contains 1 period { (1990,2013) }
Count List contains 1 entry { 1 }

 1995 - 2000
Period List contains 3 periods { (1990,1995), (1995,2000), (2000,2013) }
Count List contains 3 entries { 1, 2, 1 }

 2010 - 2020
Period List contains 5 periods { (1990,1995), (1995,2000), (2000,2010), (2010, 2013), (2013, 2020) }
Count List contains 5 entries { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 }

 1992 - 1999
Period List contains 7 periods { (1990,1992), (1992,1995), (1995,1999), (1999,2000), (2000,2010), (2010, 2013), (2013, 2020) }
Count List contains 7 entries { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) arrange in assending order year wise starting from the largest series.
2) count the years for largest series for whole data set
3) then identify the largest count.
4) the largest count is your answer for years... this can be done in Algo.