# Algorithm to find an interval with the highest summed weight of weighted overlapping intervals

Tags: algorithm

Well, I think it's hard to explain, so I've made a figure to show that.

[image]

As we can see in this figure, there are 6 intervals of time. Each one has its weight. Higher the opacity, higher the weight. I want an algorithm to find the interval with the highest summed weight. In the case of the figure, it'd be the overlapping of the intervals 5 and 6, which is the area with highest opacity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Split each interval into start and end points.
- Sort the points.
- Start with a sum of 0.
- Iterate through the points using a [sweep-line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm):

  - If you get a start point:

    - Increase the sum by the value of the corresponding interval.
    - If the sum count is higher than the best sum so far, store this start point and set a flag.
  - If you get an end point:

    - If the flag is set, store the stored start point and this end point with the current sum as the best interval so far and reset the flag.
    - Decrease the count by the value of the corresponding interval.

This is derived from [the answer I wrote here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155454/algorithm-to-find-time-period-whee-number-of-elements-are-maximum), which is based on the unweighted version, i.e. finding the maximum number of overlapping intervals, rather than the maximum summed weight.

**Example:**

For this example:

[image]

The start / end points will be sorted as: (`S` = start, `E` = end)

```
1S, 1E, 2S, 3S, 2E, 3E, 4S, 5S, 4E, 6S, 5E, 6E
```

Iterating through them, you'll set the flag on `1S`, `5S` and `6S`, and you'll store the respective intervals at `1E`, `4E` and `5E` (which is the first end-points you get to after the above start points).

You won't set the flag on `2S`, `3S` or `4S`, as the sum will be lower than the best sum so far.

Comment: It's a very interesting algorithm to solve this problem. I'll let the question open for a while to see if better answers appears, but I'll probably accept yours. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm logic can be derived from the figure. Assuming that resolution of time intervals is 1 min, then an array can be created and used for all the calculations:

1. create the array of 24 * 60 elements and fill it with 0 weights;
2. for each time interval add the weight of this interval to the corresponding part of the array;
3. find a maximum summed weight by iterating the array;
4. iterate over the array again and output array index (time) with the maximal summed weight.

This algorithm can be modified for a slightly different task, if you need to have interval indices in the output. In this case the array should contain list of the input time interval indices as a second dimension (or it can be a separate array, depending on particular language).

UPD. I was curious if this simple algorithm is significantly slower than more elegant one suggested by @Dukeling. I coded both algorithms and created an input generator to estimate their performance.

Generator:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -v n=$1 '
BEGIN {
  tmax = 24 * 60; wmax = 100;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    t1 = int(rand() * tmax);
    t2 = int(rand() * tmax);
    w  = int(rand() * wmax);
    if (t2 >= t1) {print t1, t2, w} else {print t2, t1, w}
  }
}' | sort -n > i.txt
```

Algorithm #1:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
{t1[++i] = $1; t2[i] = $2; w[i] = $3}
END {
  for (i in t1) {
    for (t = t1[i]; t <= t2[i]; t++) {
      W[t] += w[i];
    }
  }
  Wmax = 0.;
  for (t in W){
    if (W[t] > Wmax) {Wmax = W[t]}
  }
  print Wmax;
  for (t in W){
    if (W[t] == Wmax) {print t}
  }
}
' i.txt > a1.txt
```

Algorithm #2:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
{t1[++i] = $1; t2[i] = $2; w[i] = $3}
END {
  for (i in t1) {
    p[t1[i] "a" i] = i "S";
    p[t2[i] "b" i] = i "E";
  }
  n = asorti(p, psorted, "@ind_num_asc");
  W = 0.; Wmax = 0.; f = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    P = p[psorted[i] ];
    k = int(P);
    if (index(P, "S") > 0) {
      W += w[k];
      if (W > Wmax) {
        f = 1;
        Wmax = W;
        to1 = t1[k]
      }
    }
    else {
      if (f != 0) {
        to2 = t2[k];
        f = 0
      }
      W -= w[k];
    }
  }
  print Wmax, to1 "-" to2
}
' i.txt > a2.txt
```

Results:

```
$ ./gen.sh 1000
$ time ./a1.sh
real    0m0.283s
$ time ./a2.sh
real    0m0.019s
$ cat a1.txt
24618
757
$ cat a2.txt
24618 757-757
$ ./gen.sh 10000
$ time ./a1.sh
real    0m3.026s
$ time ./a2.sh
real    0m0.144s
$ cat a1.txt
252452
746
$ cat a2.txt
252452 746-746
$ ./gen.sh 100000
$ time ./a1.sh
real    0m34.127s
$ time ./a2.sh
real    0m1.999s
$ cat a1.txt
2484719
714
$ cat a2.txt
2484719 714-714
```

The simple on is ~20x slower.