# Find efficient algorithm for grouping timstamps by X time

Tags: algorithm

I have a question I was asked and wanted to see if there was a better solution. so I am asking you the same question. I was unable to find anything online about it.

Given an unsorted array of tuples in the form (timstamp (seconds), resource_id) representing the access time of a given resource.

return the most accesses out of any of the resources in any 5 min block of time.

The return will be a tuple with resource id and single number for max accesses.

ex)
input:

```
[("400", "1"), ("405", "2"),("605", "4"), ("505", "3"),("604", "1"), ("1505", "3"), ("1205", "2")]
```

output: ("1", 2)

Comment: `wanted to see if there was a better solution` -- what is the solution you have so far? Hint: If you convert a time stamp `t` into an interval `[t, t+300]`, your problem becomes [finding the maximum overlapping intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155454/find-the-time-period-with-the-maximum-number-of-overlapping-intervals).

Comment: Sounds like a 1D sweep line problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm So it can be very much simplified, by going through the list (sorted by timestamp) with two iterators. In each step deciding (by a simple comparison of timestamps), whether to add one more element or remove one element. As data structure you could keep an array of resources with the number of accesses in the current 5 min block. Adding one resource access element, means increasing an array element, removing one resource access element means  decreasing the respective array element.

Answer (score 1):

In the following I will use Ruby (in simplified form) to explain the algorithms proposed. With some explanation, the code should be understandable to readers who do not know the language. I find that clearer than describing it in "algorithm speak" and more helpful for implementation.

For the moment forget about `resource_id`'s. I will deal with that at the end.

**Construct O(nlog(n)) method `max_interval_coverage`**

The method `max_interval_coverage` will take an array of timestamps as it's argument and return a hash giving the maximum number of timestamps that appear in a 5-minute interval and the index of the timestamp at which that interval begins.

Clearly, (as suggested by @kdsquare in a comment) a 5-minute (299 second) interval containing the greatest number of timestamps will begin at one of the timestamps.

If the timestamps are not sorted, sort them, which is O(nlog(n)). Suppose

```
timestamps = [100, 340, 460, 512, 733, 999, 1462, 1581, 1622, 1699, 1833]
```

Now create an array comprised of the elements of `timestamps` to which an additional timestamp is appended, one that is larger than the last timestamp in the sorted array by at least `300`:

```
ts = timestamps << Float::INFINITY
  #=> [100, 340, 460, 512, 733, 999, 1462, 1581, 1622, 1699, 1833, Infinity]
```

First I will construct a helper method.

```
def coverage(ts, start_idx)
  idx_arr = (0..ts.size-1).to_a 
  n = ts[start_idx] + 299
  idx_arr.bsearch { |j| ts[j] > n } - start_idx
end
```

For example,

```
coverage(ts, 6)
  #=> 4
```

This tells us that the 5-minute minute interval beginning at `timestamps[6] #=> 1462` (ending at `1462 + 299 #=> 1761`) contains `4` timestamps: `1462`, `1581`, `1622` and `1699`. (Notice that the interval `1581` to `1880` also contains 4 timestamps).

The calculation

```
idx_arr.bsearch { |j| ts[j] > n }
```

finds the smallest index `j` for which

```
ts[j] > ts[i] + 299
```

It is guaranteed to find such an index because of the "large-enough" value I appended to `timespaces`.

See [Array#bsearch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch).

By subtracting `start_idx` from the index returned by `bsearch` we obtain the number of `timespaces` within the 5-minute interval `ts[start_idx]` to `ts[start_idx] + 299`.

---

As array `idx_arr` is computed each time the method is called, I will instead pass it as a third argument:

```
def coverage(ts, idx_arr, start_idx)
  n = ts[start_idx] + 299
  idx_arr.bsearch { |j| ts[j] > n } - start_idx
end
```

---

We can now define the method `max_interval_coverage`.

```
def max_interval_coverage(timestamps)
  ts = timestamps + [Float::INFINITY]
  idx_arr = (0..ts.size-1).to_a
  start_idx = (0..timestamps.size-1).max_by { |i| coverage(ts, idx_arr, i) }
  { start_idx: start_idx, coverage: coverage(ts, idx_arr, start_idx) }
end
```

```
max_interval_coverage(timestamps)
  #=> {:start_idx=>6, :coverage=>4}
```

---

The line:

```
start_idx = (0..timestamps.size-1).max_by { |i| coverage(ts, idx_arr, i) }
  #=> (0..10).max_by { |i| coverage(ts, idx_arr, i) }
```

computes the index `i` of the element of `timestamps` (and of `ts`) for which

```
coverage(ts, idx_arr, i)
```

is maximum. See [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

`0..10` is a range of integers from `0` to `10`, inclusive, that correspond to indices of the elements of `timestamps`. The expression computing `start_idx` reads, "find the element `i` of the range `0..10` (the index of `timestamps`) for which `coverage(ts, idx_arr, i)` is maximized".

```
coverage(ts, idx_arr, start_idx)
```

is called again in order to obtain the value of `:coverage` in the hash that is returned.

---

`bsearch_index` is O(log(n)), so executing it for each element of `timespaces` is O(nlog(n)), the same as sorting `timespaces`, so it is also the computational complexity of the algorithm.

---

To better explain how the Ruby code above works, I have modified it to display calculations made at each step.

```
idx_arr = ​[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
ts = [100, 340, 460, 512, 733, 999, 1462, 1581, 1622, 1699, 1833,     
(0..timestamps.size-1).each do |i|
  n = ts[i] + 299
  j = idx_arr.bsearch { |j| ts[j] > n }
  puts "time #{ts[i]} to #{n}, first after interval index = #{j}, value = #{ts[j]}, j-i = #{j-i}"
end
```

displays the following.

```
time  100 to  399, 1st aft interval idx =  2, val =  460, j-i = 2
time  340 to  639, 1st aft interval idx =  4, val =  733, j-i = 3
time  460 to  759, 1st aft interval idx =  5, val =  999, j-i = 3
time  512 to  811, 1st aft interval idx =  5, val =  999, j-i = 2
time  733 to 1032, 1st aft interval idx =  6, val = 1462, j-i = 2
time  999 to 1298, 1st aft interval idx =  6, val = 1462, j-i = 1
time 1462 to 1761, 1st aft interval idx = 10, val = 1833, j-i = 4
time 1581 to 1880, 1st aft interval idx = 11, val = Inf,  j-i = 4
time 1622 to 1921, 1st aft interval idx = 11, val = Inf,  j-i = 3
time 1699 to 1998, 1st aft interval idx = 11, val = Inf,  j-i = 2
time 1833 to 2132, 1st aft interval idx = 11, val = Inf,  j-i = 1
```

**Map maximum number of timespaces per 5-minute interval to resource_id's**

Suppose, as in the example given in the question,

```
arr = [["400", "1"], ["405", "2"], ["605", "4"], ["505", "3"],
       ["604", "1"], ["1505", "3"], ["1205", "2"]]
```

Construct the following hash.

```
h = {}
arr.each do |timestamp, id|
  ts = timestamp.to_i
  h[ts] = [] if !h.key?(ts)
  h[ts] << id
end
h #=> {400=>["1"], 405=>["2"], 605=>["4"], 505=>["3"], 604=>["1"],
  #    1505=>["3"], 1205=>["2"]}
```

I've saved the values in arrays in case two or more timestamps are equal.

Then

```
timestamps = h.keys.sort
  #=> [400, 405, 505, 604, 605, 1205, 1505]

g = max_interval_coverage(timestamps)
  #=> {:start_idx=>0, :coverage=>5}
```

so the desired result is:

```
{ resource_ids: h[timestamps[g[:start_idx]]], max_per_interval: g[:coverage] }
  #=> {:resource_ids=>["1"], :max_per_interval=>5}
```

This coincides with the stated requirement, "return the most accesses out of any of the resources in any 5 min. block of time.", but not with the desired return value for the example (which would be `{:resource_ids=>["1"], :max_per_interval=>2}`), which appears inconsistent with requirements.

Comment: This is almost right, but it misses a preprocessing step that my comment also missed: you need to partition the timestamps based on 'resource id' before running this algorithm once for each resource's timestamp list.

Comment: @kcsquared, thanks. I will look into that when I have time later today. Perhaps you are like me: while reading questions I often start thinking about how to solve what I think is being asked, getting sidetracked from gaining a complete understanding of the question, which is in fact different than what I had expected.

Comment: This is really a minor change to answer OP's exact output request; you've already solved the hard part. The necessary addition is: Given the initial list of (timestamp, ID) pairs, partition it into separate lists based on the ID values. I don't know enough ruby to add it in, but a hashmap from ID to lists of timestamps is all that's needed. OP wants the maximum value returned by your algorithm on each individual list.

Comment: @kcsquared, my reading was different; that the OP merely wants the resource_id associated with associated with the timestamp of the beginning of the interval that contains a maximum number of intervals, but I'm not sure. In any case, I think I'm done. The question would have been better if it was limited to finding the interval containing a maximum number  time-stamps; the business about the  resource_id is a distraction.